# Highest result based off category incorrect

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get the highest produced unit of a specific ReplayID. However, on some, but not all, of my results it does not actually display the highest value.

```
Column =
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( 'Ref - Player 1 - Elite Unit'[Produced] ),
    ALLEXCEPT (
        'Ref - Player 1 - Elite Unit',
        'Ref - Player 1 - Elite Unit'[ReplayID]
    )
)
```

```
ReplayID    Unit           Produced Column
11013348    Warpprism       3       9
11013348    Phoenix         9       9
11013348    Archon          8       9
11013348    Immortal        6       9
11013348    Hightemplar     16      9
11191501    Hightemplar     10      5
11191501    Archon          5       5
11191501    Immortal        3       5
11191501    Phoenix         0       5
```

I expect the result for 11013348 to be 16 and the result for 11191501 to be 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because "Produced" column contains text instead of numbers.

As text, "10" is ranked lower than "5", because it is ranked by the first symbol ("1" vs "5"). The same is true for "16" vs "9".

To fix it, just convert "Produced" column to numeric type (change field type in Power Query).

Comment: That fixed it worked like a charm! I appreciate it!